# Ajax Callback -> messages form PHP via JSON to JS and output to DIV

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

This is a newbie-question. I have never learned JS and it is very hard for me to do easy things..

I have a PHP-Script, which gets data via JS from the Website. The PHP-Script updates the database and Returns a success via the following code-line:

```
echo json_encode(array('success'=>'true'));
```

I have Setup a function, which does something, when "success" is returned:

```
success: function(){
  ....
}
```

Now I want to extend it a little bit. My PHP-Script would also return a message, which should be output into a DIV.

It would Output something like:

"error-msg"=>"Could not write to DB."
or
"success-msg"=>"Data successfully saved in DB."

I really don't know how to check if the returned data is a "error-msg" or success-msg.
I don't know how to get the msg string and also how to Display it in a defined DIV.

Could you help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `success_msg` and `error_msg`, you could just use `status_msg and status` (in your PHP script).

`status_msg` would contain the text.
status would contain `"success" or "error"`. You could also use any other kind of marker you like.

To check the status of the message in Javascript,

```
var response = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(response.status_msg); //display the message    
if(response.status == "success"){    
    //do something    
}    
else {    
    //do something    
}
```

After you get the message, you can display it in a DIV using

```
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = response.status_msg;
```

The HTML file would look like

```
<div id="message">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the code! Could you please tell me, what to insert here: (<response_from_server>)?
I'm not sure on how to implement bootstrap-Markup in your example. I want to use alert-Markup like: <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">...</div> If the message is an error it should use "alert-danger" and "alert-succes" on success. I also don't know, if I put your Code inside the listed success-function in my main-question ;-)

Comment: Replace <response_from_server> by a Javascript variable which contains the response got back from the server. For using bootstrap markup, you need to use addClass and removeClass functions from the DOM API. Also, the code I have proposed is supposed to go inside your function. If I may ask, how does your code enter the success function? Is it a handler provided by some library?